# how to pass session variable into view using laravel4

Tags: laravel-4

I want to pass logged in id into my view page.i got the id in the function of user_login_submits.

Actually i want to get the id in one more function in the same controller.
how to get the session id in controller..
Normally session put its enough i did like that.

Here is my code anyone can check and tel me what need to change here

**Controller**

```
      public function user_login_submits()
     {
          $inputs = Input::all();

             $uname = Input::get('username');
             $password = Input::get('password');

             $logincheck=Userlogin::login_checks($uname,$password);
            if($logincheck == 1)
            {
            $id=Session::get('customer_id');


            return Redirect::to('businessprio/create_news?p=1');

            }
            else if($logincheck == 0)
            {

                 //echo "fail";
                return Redirect::to('businessprio/create');
            }

         }
```

**Model**

```
    public static function login_checks($uname,$password)
     {
        $check = DB::table('customer_login')
        ->where('username','=',$uname)
        ->where('password','=',$password)->get();


      if($check)
       {
           //Session::put(['customer_id'=>'value']);
        Session::put('customer_id', $check[0]->customer_id);
        Session::put('username', $check[0]->username);
        return 1;
      }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't pass it to model, instead i would do it in controller itself,

```
public function user_login_submits()
{
    $uname = Input::get('username');
    $password = Input::get('password');

    $check = DB::table('customer_login')
            ->where('username','=',$uname)
            ->where('password','=',$password)->count();
    if($check==1)
    {
    $id=Session::get('customer_id');    
    return Redirect::to('businessprio/create_news?p=1');
    }
    else
    {
    return Redirect::to('businessprio/create');    
    }
}
```

**Recommendation :**

But i would strongly recommend you to do it by Auth::attempt i.e., to follow the clean one

```
public function user_login_submits()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $userEmail, 'password' => $userPassword])) {
        return Redirect::to('businessprio/create_news?p=1');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('businessprio/create');    
    }
}
```

If you do so, then you can access the Default checking for authenticated user

```
Auth::check()
```

Get the Logged in user details by

```
Auth::user()->id
Auth::user()->username
```

**Note :** To use default `Auth::attempt` you should use the User Model too.